# Redirect output of command back into prompt (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I redirect output of a process back in to the command prompt without going to disk first?

I have a utility that generates commands that I want to run but it outputs them to the console. I'm having to create a temp file when I don't want too do that.

e.g., `echo test 1>&0`

would run test as if it were typed.

Doesn't work of course but that is effectively what I'm trying to achieve.

I thought about writing a simple utility that would take the input and then execute it in a shell(probably could be done with a batch file) but surely there is some simple way?

Comment: You can pipe to _another_ (child) CMD: `echo start notepad | cmd`. This will _execute_ the command(s), but any changes done by those command(s) to the CMD process itself, like `CD` or `SET`, affect only the child CMD and are lost when it exits, not the parent; that may or may not be a problem depending on what you want. For _one_ command you can also futz with `for /f` something like `for /f %x in ('echo start notepad') do set cmd=%x` then (next line) `%cmd%`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, unfortunately the output is a series of commands. I thought about using another cmd but wasn't sure about how it would handle the paths and such. I ultimately just modified the utility to be able to execute the commands in it's own shell rather than print them out. Luckily since I had the source code I could do that. Not sure why it's so difficult to redirect the output of something back in to the terminal though.